# How to order food on Zakynthos

Tags: food-and-drink, greece

Short and stupid question: How to order delivery from a restaurant on Zakynthos?

I've seen some drivers but I have not managed to find a general website/app for food restaurant delivery. Very most restaurants don't have a website or menu available online so calling the restaurant to order is quite pointless.

Comment: Have you tried Tripadvisor's [Zakynthos Delivery Restaurants](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g189462-zfp19-Zakynthos_Ionian_Islands.html)? At least one review links to the restaurant's website.

Comment: In some places (no idea if that applies there) it still works the old-fashioned way: you have already been there, either know the menu or got one while there, and can order by phone on that basis. What is this Internet thing you are talking about? :-/

Comment: I managed to get one order done through e-food.gr but they offer only have 5 or so restaurants. The Tripadvisor stuff is useless, it's not up to date and most restaurants there are closed because winter-covid-season

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most popular food ordering services in Greece are [e-food](https://www.e-food.gr/) and [wolt](https://wolt.com/el).

E-food has a huge list of affiliated restaurants all around the country, and they have a good search engine that allows for searching specific meals, sorting by minimum order amount, delivery time, etc. They also have a rating system for the restaurants, and public comments on them.

Wolt works a bit differently, because the restaurants don't need to be affiliated with them, they go and pickup a takeaway from the restaurant and deliver it with their own fleet of drivers.

Comment: Thank you so much! Wolt isn't available on Zakythos but, if you're checking at the right time, e-food has some more restaurants available!